# csvReared.Read method dosn't read the memory stream

Tags: c#, memorystream, csvreader

Please tell me tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
   var writer = new StreamWriter(mem);
   writer.Write(csvText);
   writer.Flush();

   using (var reader = new StreamReader(mem))
   {
       mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
       {
            while (csvReader.Read())
            {
               // some unreach code
            }
        }
     }

   writer.Dispose();
}
```

The code inside while is unreached, and I can't understand why. csvText is a not empty string variable.
But the reader can't read it. I understand that most likely I made a stupid mistake, but I will be glad to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the MemoryStream and StreamWriter just to convert your string to a stream. Just do `using (var reader = new StringReader(csvText))` and remove everything before.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately is not work for me.

Comment: After writing the MemoryStream you need to set the position to zero before reading.

Comment: @jdweng He is already doing that at `mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`.